# How can I use mock to return None for parse known args?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, argparse, python-unittest

Below I have a function that returns the two dates based on command line input. How can I use mock to make it so that I can perform unit testing on the else statement?

```
# time from of pull
def time_frame():
    """
    checks for optional user input for start and end date of data pull
    creates start and end date for query
    :return: start and end date
    """
    # get the dates
    args, leftovers = get_the_args()

    if args.start_dt is not None and args.end_dt is not None:

        return args.start_dt, args.end_dt

    else:

        # get today
        the_today_start_date, the_today_end_date = get_dates_from_today()

        return the_today_start_date, the_today_end_date
```

I have tried using `mock_get_the_args.return_value = mock.Mock(return_value=None), mock.Mock()` to make it so that the args output of the `get_the_args()` function returns None when this section of my unit test runs? What do I need to change my mock.Mock() thats represents the `args` variable for this to work?

Below is the unit test so far:

```
# the time frame
@mock.patch('src.toolkit.get_dates_from_today')
@mock.patch('src.toolkit.get_the_args')
def test_time_frame(mock_get_the_args, mock_get_dates_from_today):
    # set some dates
    start_date = '2019-01-01'
    end_date = '2019-01-01'
    # mocking
    mock_get_the_args.return_value = mock.Mock(), mock.Mock()
    mock_get_dates_from_today.return_value = mock.Mock(), mock.Mock()

    start_date, end_date = time_frame() 
    mock_get_the_args.assert_called_once()

    mock_get_the_args.return_value = mock.Mock(return_value=None), mock.Mock()
    start_date, end_date = time_frame() 
    mock_get_dates_from_today.assert_called_once()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit testing with `argparse` code is a bit tricky because it normally expects input from the command line.  But testing itself uses the commandline (possibly with its own argparse parser).

I assume `get_the_args` sets up a parser, and returns `parser.parse_known_args()`.

For testing purposes, it's convenient to give yourself the option of providing an explicit `argv` list.

e.g.:

```
def time_frame(argv=None):
    """
    checks for optional user input for start and end date of data pull
    creates start and end date for query
    :return: start and end date
    """
    # get the dates
    args, leftovers = get_the_args(argv)
    ...
```

where `get_the_args` uses `parse_known_args(argv)`.

If `argv` is None, then it parses the regular commandline.  But you can provide any list of strings that generates the desired `args` and `extras`.  In effect you can simulate a commandline.

Another option is to define an `args` namespace object, eg. `args = argparse.Namespace(start_dt=None, end_dt='foobar')`.  Then you can use `args.start_dt` as before.

Another thing that makes testing easier is to make the `parser` is run only when the code is run as a script, not when it is imported.  That is, put it in the `if **name** =='**main**': block.